# Obtener ocampo de un objeto en Firebase usando Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic

Buenas tardes, me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación que implementa un carrito de compras, cada orden que genere el usuario,la guardo dentro de cada usuario mediante el uid, y para esto, dentro de la orden se genera el objeto del carrito con todos sus campos, pero al momento de querer obtener esos datos no me lo permte. Adjunto los códigos que tengo:
[image: Aquí se muestra como se almacenan el número de ordenes en el documento de cada usuario, y se almacena dentro de ellas el objeto del carrito]

Con este código recupero todas las ordenes que se almacenan en cada usuario.

```
userOrders;

  constructor(private aF: AngularFirestore, private aS: AuthService) {
    const ordenes = aF.doc(`users/${this.aS.getInfo()}`);
    this.userOrders = ordenes.valueChanges();
  }
```

Con este código muestro las ordenes de cada usuario en su respectiva tab:

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-card *ngFor="let p of ((userOrders | async)?.ordenes)">
            <ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-title>{{ p.name }}</ion-card-title>
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content>
                <img src={{p.img}}>
                <br>
                <ion-card-subtitle>{{p.desc}}</ion-card-subtitle>
                <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
                    <ion-col size="4">
                        <ion-label color="secondary">
                            <b>Total: {{ p.total}}</b>
                        </ion-label>
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col size="8" class="ion-text-right">
                        <b>Recoger en sucursal: {{p.sucursal}}</b>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col>
                        <b>Hora: {{p.horarecoger}}</b>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-list>
```

p.name y p.desc, se supone que son campos del objeto cart pero no me los muestra en la aplicación, por lo tanto sé que no está accediendo al objeto cart.

[image: Solamente carga los valores que están fuera del objeto cart]

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, se lo agradecería muchísimo!

Comment: No te los muestra probablemente porque tienes un error en el código que interrumpe la ejecución. El error dice que `screen.orientation.lock()` no está disponible en el dispositivo. Prueba comentando el código que se encarga de la orientación y prueba tu código con la consola limpia de errores.

Comment: No, ese error, es por que el navegador no soporta esa extensión, ya que es para bloquear el modo landscape

Comment: No esta accediendo por que es otro array de objetos.

Comment: Tienes que hacer adentro otro ngfor para poder recorrer ese cart, por ejemplo ahora abajo del ngfor base, haz *ngFor="let o of p.cart"

Comment: ya con eso puedes poner o.name y o.desc, saludos :)